# What is the black, flexible, line filled with water in my garden that’s deeper and thicker than my drip irrigation line?

Tags: leak, irrigation

I was digging in my front yard (in San Diego, that matters), and I nicked this line, and some water seeped out.  It was buried about 10 inches deep. It’s significantly wider than the drip irrigation tubing that’s installed in the yard and, nothing comes out when I turn on any of my irrigation valves.  It’s flexible like drip irrigation tubing.  It has an OD of 1”.  My other drip system tubing is 0.7”.

It’s not going or coming toward or away from anything (eg irrigation valves).  It’s kind of close to our main waterline, but given that it isn’t spraying wildly in all directions I’m guessing it’s not related to that.

The obvious possibility is an abandoned irrigation line, but I’m hesitant to just bury it, and hope everything’s OK.

The last photo shows the interior of a small section I cut out. It looks like it’s got some mud and some roots in it.

What else could it be?

What should I do? Patch and rebury it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: All but certainly old irrigation system in that part of the world. Or old abandoned municipal water line if they buried them that shallow.